# serialize and deserialize objects from different location

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, serialization

I have two separate programs that need to share information.  This sharing will be done by one app placing an `XML serialized` object in a database, and the other app retrieving it on a different machine.  The objects share the same `variables` but the `properties` and `methods` are different.

- How exact do the classes have to match between the two programs?
- Is the match line by line or just variable, property, and method names?

---

I ended up using the `Newtonsoft.Json` library instead of `xml` and used the `<JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)>` and `JsonProperty()` attributes to control what got serialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not specify which kind of serialization you were after.

The standard NET binary serializer is not well suited for data exchange between 2 different assemblies.  When you go to deserialize, you'll get an an error similar to `[Culture].[Assembly].[Version].SourceClass` cannot be deserialized to `[Culture].[Assembly].[Version].DestClass`.  This will happen even if the classes are identical.

There are several ways around this.  A) Use the same service DLL on both sides to do the serializing B) trick it into deserializing by using an override to report a matching Culture-Assembly-Version-Class, but that seems dodgy or C) use XML serialization, but that makes for very wordy output, which is also readable.

For Binary Serialization, rather than the NET binary formatter, there is [ProtoBuf-NET](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) which is faster, produces much smaller output and uses nearly identical syntax.

`How exact do the classes have to match between the two programs`

ProtoBuf uses a numeric index rather than property name, so they shouldn't have to be too similar.  Of course there has to be some similarity or the destination may not have a clue what the data represents. The code in the class can be quite different because it stays put.

Comment: Because of the deployment environment third party solutions are absolute last resort only.  I added the kind of serialization to the question.

Comment: @Wayne does one app send the serialized info elsewhere to be consumed, or is this a same machine share like by file?

Comment: @Plutonix It will be serialized by one machine then consumed by several other machines on the network.

Comment: @Wayne XML has some limitations, but they may not apply.  Example: the basic one won't do a Dictionary, so you have to use `DataContractSerializer`, each consumer would almost certainly have to have the same class in it if just to load the data, but that could just be a `List(Of foo)` depending on the data.  Also, the output is enormous (test: List of 54 settings = 12K in XML; 7 **sets** of 54 settings is 6k via PBN).  [Here is a decent article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98126/Comparing-NET-XML-Serializers-Part-One) comparing XML serializers.  But you should keep PBN in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization stores only the *data* for an object - member variables, properties, etc. As long as the data types are compatible, it should work. You do not need a line by line match for the functions.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain You are right.. Let me edit that part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the serializer you are using. Some require a perfect match, others tend to be more loosely coupled to the objects.

> How exact do the classes have to match between the two programs?

Well, not at all. But they should be similar in some way because otherwise the serialization doesn't make sense.

> Is the match line by line or variables and method names?

As, stated above: there must be some overlap. Usually the property names must be the same. But of course you can also provide a custom mapping.

Take a look at the Newtonsoft library, u can use it (for json) like this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Unit>>(result);
```

It's independent of the object method that serialized the string.