# Exception with assembly when i deserialize in other project

Tags: c#, exception, serialization, deserialization

I have a program that serializes a list of object of my class. In an other program i have created the same class and all worked fine.
But yesterday i have changed assembly name of program that serialize and now i can't deserialize any file because i have an exception "impossible find assembly "... " versione "..." ....
How i can resolve this problem ?
I serialized so:

```
public static void serialize(BodyCustom[] bodySerialized, String path)
    {
        FileStream stream = null;
        try
        {
            BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
            bFormatter.Serialize(stream, bodySerialized);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.Close();


        }
```

and deserialized:

```
public static BodyCustom[] deserialize(String path)
    {
        BodyCustom[] bodyDeserialized = null;
        FileStream stream = null;

        try
        {
            BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
            bodyDeserialized = (BodyCustom[])bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }
        if (stream != null)
            stream.Close();

        return bodyDeserialized;
    }
```

This is the exception:

```
$exception  {"Impossibile to find assembly 'FitnessRecordingUtility, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."}  System.Exception {System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException}
```

Comment: Provide the entire exception text as well as inner exceptions.

Comment: i have added the exception

Comment: that error message doesnt sounds quite right.  can you add the assembly names involved?  also, are you trying to serialize in one app and deserialize to another or is there something like a DLL handling both?

Comment: i serialize with an app and the created files are used in another app that deserialize them. Surely before they had the same assembly name and now no. When i open the file serialized i read the assembly that then less in second app

Comment: The error message doesnt match, but from your comment, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23788412/1070452) might explain what is going on.

Comment: I have resolved. I have created a DLL with the class BodyCustom and i have imported this between the referements of the second project. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved. I have created a DLL with the class BodyCustom with the same assembly of the first project and i have imported this between the referements of the second project. Many thanks –